# Opening winform from wpf application programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, c#-4.0

How would I go about opening a winform from a wpf application? This needs to be done through code, but the normal function

```
Form.Show();
```

will not work. I need something that will allow me to change the visibility of the form, but I am not able to access any of the gui related functions within this form.

Comment: What do you mean by "will not work"? Do you get an error? If so, what is it? There's no obvious reason why this wouldn't work, so you'll need to provide more information.

Comment: Will not work means in this case that I am unable to access the show function when calling it on said form. I am trying to access this form from another project within the solution. For some reason it worked when a winforms project was calling it, just not the wpf project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can work with the Windows Form the same way in a WPF application as you would from a Windows Forms application, provided you have the proper references.  This should work fine:

```
YourForm form = new YourForm();
form.Show();
```

However, I would typically recommend trying to rework this to include the Windows Forms content as a UserControl within a WPF Window using a [WindowsFormsHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost.aspx) control.  This tends to be a little cleaner, since the window parenting works a bit more cleanly (since they're all WPF windows).

Comment: @Tim make sure your form is defined correctly - but it should be this simple...  Are you getting compiler errors on the form?  Is it not deriving from Form now somehow?

Comment: I will have to look at the code when I get back to work, but I am going to try to host that form from a WindowsFormsHost and see if that helps.

Comment: Well, I open the project today and tested it out. It worked. It must have been some build issue/bug with VS.